# Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type - java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I am working on a spring boot application and trying to deserialize a json using jackson.

I get the below error when I try to do it.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'student.StudentId' for property 'student.ref.null'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'student.StudentId': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:594)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:682)
... 104 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'student.StudentId': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:589)
    ... 105 common frames omitted
```

I do not understand why this happens since the StudentId class has a method to convert String to a StudentId.

```
@Data
@Getter(onMethod_ = {@JsonValue})
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)

public class StudentId {
    private final long value;
    @JsonCreator
    public static StudentId from(long value) {
        return new StudentId(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static StudentId from(String value) {
        long longValue = Long.parseLong(value);
        return StudentId.from(longValue);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static StudentId from(BigDecimal value) {
        long longValue = value.longValue();
        return StudentId.from(longValue);
    }

    public String stringValue() {
        return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

Below is the related part of the json, which I am trying to convert. To begin with,the StudentId here is a long value, which should have been handled by the method which handles the long value. So I am not sure where this goes wrong.

```
"data":{
     "Student1":{
        "type":"undergrad",
        "studentId":501043
      }
}
```

Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong or how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@Getter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public final class StudentId {

    private final long value;

    @JsonCreator
    public static StudentId from(@JsonProperty("studentId") long value) {
        return new StudentId(value);
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static StudentId from(@JsonProperty("studentId") String value) {
        return from(Long.parseLong(value));
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static StudentId from(@JsonProperty("studentId") BigDecimal value) {
        return from(value.longValue());
    }

}
```

This class successfully parse following json:

```json
{
   "type": "undergrad",
   "studentId": 501043
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Oleg. But still I get the below error for me. Since I have a method to convert numbers (long / int ) wondering whether you got the same issue.



Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `student.StudentId` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (501043)